# Show C++ source files in Android Studio when debugging with lldb

Tags: c++, android-studio, debugging, lldb

I have an Android application with native c++ librairies.
I can debug c++ code with lldb, I can break, I can see the stack, the variables and their values.
The command 'source info' displays the correct break line code.
I use the command 'settings set target.source-map' to map the source code files, the command seems to work fine, no error, but Android studio don't open the corresponding source files in the editor... nothing happens when I double click in the debugger stack.
Sometime ago, it works correctly, I don't know if something changed in my compilation process or in Android studio, but it doesn't work anymore.
Any ideas ?

Comment: The final check on the lldb side would be that the command `source list -y foo.cpp:12` (but with a valid file & line number for your project) in the Android Studio debugger console does list source.  "source info" works off the debug info's line table and doesn't depend on actually finding the source files.  But `source list` has to find the files.

Comment: The command `source list` displays nothing... but `source info` does with the correct file and line number. So where is my problem ?

Comment: `source info` only consults the debug information (and any source-map settings) but doesn't require the files to exist.  Similarly the source-map settings don't require any of the map entries to be extant.  It sounds like either the source files that the debug-info/source-map entries points to don't exist or are not readable.

Comment: However the path I provide for the source files is valid, I get an error otherwise. How can I test if they are readable by lldb because they are text files so obviously in a text editor I can read them.

Comment: lldb has a `platform shell` command which runs a sub shell with all the same permissions as lldb.  If `platform shell cat <file path>` produces text, then lldb should be able to open the files.

Comment: `lldb platform shell` can read files on the device. `lldb plaform shell <file on device path>` works. `lldb plaform shell <file on computer path>` failed -> No such file or directory. And the command `settings set target.source-map` accepts only local computer path. `settings set target.source-map <binaries path> <dir path on device>` failed -> the replacement path doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not getting out of it. Other ideas ?